# How to test if a method has been invoked in Android Instrumentation Tests?

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, android-instrumentation

```
@Test
public void testWhenUserNameAndPasswordAreEnteredShouldAttemptLogin() throws Exception {
    LoginView loginView = Mockito.mock(LoginView.class);
    Mockito.when(loginView.getUserName()).thenReturn("George");
    Mockito.when(loginView.getPassword()).thenReturn("aaaaaa");
    loginPresenter.setLoginView(loginView);
    loginPresenter.onLoginClicked();
    Mockito.verify(loginPresenter).attemptLogin(loginView.getUserName(), loginView.getPassword());
}
```

This is my test, but as `loginPresenter` is a `class` generated from `AndroidAnnotations` and it is `final`, I cannot `spy` on it.

So is there another way (not necessarily using mockito) to verify that this method has been invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) lets you mock final classes and methods (and static methods, etc).

Comment: How do I integrate PowerMock with my existing code?

Comment: The documentation is well explained https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockFinal. Basically, you must annotate your test classes with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest(MyFinalClass.class). Then mock its behavious like in mockito: `MyFinalClass mock = createMock(MyFinalClass.class);

    expect(mock.myMethod()).andReturn(whatever);`

Comment: Thanks, I just read the docs but I couldnt find a way to use PowerMock in Android Studio.. only maven and some jars. Pretty laconic

Comment: btw isn't there any other way? some assertion or reflection by Junit or something?

Comment: To use it in Android Studio, I just put in the build.gradle, into dependencies: `testCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.3') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }`.
I don't know how to do it by reflection.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Hopefully it will work with `androidTestCompile`

Comment: Should this `junit4:1.6.3'` match my junit version?

Comment: No. It's the PowerMock version. The current one I think is 1.6.4